# Google font looks different in Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox, fonts

I'm using [Maven Pro font](https://fonts.google.com/specimen/Maven+Pro) from Google but I noticed some letter looks different in Chrome and Firefox, like letter a for example:

[image: fontexample]

This problem doesn't happen in Google fonts website. I tried to put this on my css stylesheet:

```
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Maven+Pro:400,500,700,900');
body{font-family:'Maven Pro', sans-serif;-webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;-moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;}
```

But it's still the same problem, What else do I need to modify to get the same look in both browsers?

Comment: Are you using Windows 7?

Comment: @AGrammerPro Yes, this also happens in macOS.

Comment: Try applying font-weight: normal to the text, I've had this cause trouble for me some time ago aswell, maybe you have the same issue.

Comment: I know there is a known issue with windows 7 fonts/font sizes displaying differently, but if it is happening on a mac then my solution will not work. Good Luck!

Comment: @Maharkus I did it but it's still same

Comment: @AGrammerPro at least could you tell me your solution for Windows 7?

Comment: I will add a solution, but I am almost positive it is not what you're looking for

Comment: @AGrammerPro thanks anyway

Answer (score 1):

Not sure, but I guess this may help:

```
html {
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

or give a shot to this one as well:

```
body {
    font-size: 100%;
    background-color: #FFF;
    font-family: 'Source Sans Pro', sans-serif;
    margin: 0;
    font-weight: lighter;
    -webkit-text-stroke: 0.7px;
```

Keep changing 0.7 if desired result not achieved.

Answer (score 0):

**This is to fix font issues on Windows 7**

- Open start menu and type **regedit**
- Locate the key
  **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\Fonts**
- Find the value **MS Sans Serif 8,10,12,14,18,24**
- Change from **SSERIFF.FON** to **SSERIFE.FON**
- Find **Courier 10,12,15**
- Change from **COURF.FON** to **COURE.FON**
- Restart your system